# Multiplicity constraint violated and cleaning deleted entities

Tags: entity-framework, devforce

Not sure of this issue EF specific or it's issue with Devforce entity manager.

Unfortunately will be hard to provide code to duplicate, but here is quick description and solution..

The way our screen works is - we provide clean EntityManager with entity graph. Then user alters entities and at the end submit changes. User can also submit changes while working.

We have following schema:

```
Trip
-TripStops
-TripAssignments
--FromTripStop
--ToTripStop
```

So, trip assignments are childs of Trip. But they also refer to Trip stops. (from and to)

Scenario 1: - WORKS -
1. Delete trip stop
2. Reassign trip assignments to other stops
3. Save entity changes

Scenario 2: - WORKS -
1. Delete trip stop
2. Add new trip stop
2. Reassign trip assignments to new stop
3. Save entity changes

Scenario 3: - FAILS -
1. Delete trip stop
2. Save entity changes
3. Add new trip stop
4. Reassign trip assignments to new stop
5. Save entity changes

So, it looks like when EF submits change with deletion it dumps entity but keeps something? Not cleaned properly?

Message also doesn't make sense becayse model looks just fine, so it seems like rules in DevForce EM get screwed up.

Multiplicity constraint violated. The Role "TripStop" of the relationship "Model.FK_TripAssignment_TripStop_ToTripStopKey" has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

**EDIT:**

We are on DevForce 7.3 (Silverlight) (latest)
See image with schema, we don't use code first. As far as database - design is legit. It also works most of the time, in real life user's don't even see error because it's only on this specific scenario.

[image]

Comment: The error message is coming from EF, but it could be how DevForce handles the save or refreshes after a deletion which causes the problem.
Can you post more info on what these entities and relationships look like?  If the model is backed by an EDMX, a screenshot of these entities may help; otherwise with a code first model maybe show the code involved.  Also, which DF version are you using?

Comment: Kim, see edit to post. I don't see anything wrong with our part. Especially that it's only happens when we do certain sequence of steps. I'm pretty sure it is reproduceable but too lazy to create simlified scenario and test project..

Comment: In some limited testing I'm not able to reproduce the error, but I probably don't have the relations defined quite the same, or my code is not consistent with yours.  Anyway, in the failing case, when you save the deleted TripStop entity, are the modified TripAssignments (the From or To trip stop key will now be null) also included in the save list? If not, that might be something to look at.